# Is it a good idea to have many dispatches in one event handler?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Could you explain if it is a good idea or not to put many dispatches on different actions in one click handler? Each dispatch has the function, which gets data from a JSON file and outputs the filtered array according to the value in the argument.

```
const handleBtnClick = () => {
        dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS_CITY.CONVERT_CITY_NAME,
            payload: convertCityNameToCoordinates(value) //finds a city name and returns coordinates of the city
        })                                               

        dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_REGION,
            payload: getRegion(value) //finds a city name and return its region
        })

        dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_POPULATION,
            payload: getPopulation(value) //return a population of provided city
        })
}
```

***Reducer***

```
export const cityReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case (ACTIONS_CITY.CONVERT_CITY_NAME): {
            return {
                ...state,
                [state.cityCoordinates]: action.payload
            }
        }
        case (ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_POPULATION): {
            return {
                ...state,
                [state.population]: action.payload
            }

        }
        case (ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_REGION): {
            return {
                ...state,
                [state.region]: action.payload
            }
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best practices is:

[Avoid Dispatching Many Actions Sequentially](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#avoid-dispatching-many-actions-sequentially)

> **Avoid dispatching many actions in a row to accomplish a larger conceptual "transaction".** This is legal, but will usually result in multiple relatively expensive UI updates, and some of the intermediate states could be potentially invalid by other parts of the application logic. Prefer dispatching a single "event"-type action that results in all of the appropriate state updates at once, or consider use of action batching addons to dispatch multiple actions with only a single UI update at the end.

Reason 1. Multiple state updates cause multiple renders.

If you are using React <18 version and dispatch many actions sequentially in `setTimeout()`, `promise.then(resolveCallback)`, you should use [batch()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) API from `react-redux` which use `React.unstable_batchedUpdates()` API underly to allow any React updates in an event loop tick to be batched together into a single render pass.

Since `handleBtnClick` seems like an event handler, you don't need to use the `batch()` API. React already uses this internally for its own event handler callbacks.

Reason 2. Intermediate states

> In addition, multiple dispatches that are conceptually part of a larger "transaction"-style update sequence will result in intermediate states that might not be considered valid

If we can update the state once, why should we update it three times?

The way to improve is to dispatch a single action with all three payloads

```
import React from 'react';

const ACTIONS_CITY = {
    CONVERT_CITY_NAME: 'CONVERT_CITY_NAME',
    CHANGE_POPULATION: 'CHANGE_POPULATION',
    CHANGE_REGION: 'CHANGE_REGION',
    CHANGE_CITY: 'CHANGE_CITY',
};

const cityReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_CITY: {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
            };
        }
        case ACTIONS_CITY.CONVERT_CITY_NAME: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [state.cityCoordinates]: action.payload,
            };
        }
        case ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_POPULATION: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [state.population]: action.payload,
            };
        }
        case ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_REGION: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [state.region]: action.payload,
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default function App() {
    const [city, dispatch] = React.useReducer(cityReducer, { cityCoordinates: '100', population: 10000, region: 'japan' });
    console.log(city);
    const handleBtnClick = () => {
        dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS_CITY.CHANGE_CITY,
            payload: {
                cityCoordinates: '120',
                population: 20000,
                region: 'U.S',
            },
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={handleBtnClick}>click me</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76656655-n99ts7?file=/src/App.tsx)

Further reading: [Should I dispatch multiple actions in a row from one action creator?](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#should-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-a-row-from-one-action-creator)

Comment: Lin, could you please explain one moment? When i am trying to `console.log(city)`, there is an old state. As react docs mention: "This is because states behaves like a snapshot. Updating state requests another render with the new state value, but does not affect the state JavaScript variable in your already-running event handler.". How does your code work in the codesandbox? How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean old state? The `console.log(city)` will execute when rendering the component, after clicking the button, the component will re-render. The  `console.log(city)`  will execute again with the new city. @Ivan Gleym

Comment: idk why, but when i throw my state to other component i get an initial state like this: state = {cityCoordinates: [], cityName: "", etc...}